# Comments in format files

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

Is it possible to add comments to the non-XML bcp/BULK INSERT format files?

This would be very helpful in scenarios where these files are treated as declarative code--because, well, code needs comments.

Haven't tried anything yet, because I'd just be throwing random chars with possible  unforeseen after-effects.

A definitive "no" would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Marc, I can find no details on adding comments to text format files. That said, and knowing that you specified "non-XML", my experience has been that xml format files are far easier to understand and easy to generate, and you can easily add comments. The only case in which a text format file is preferred is if you wish to skip a column, and that case can be covered by bulk inserting into a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest to a definitive negative answer is the fact that there is neither a single mention of comments in the documentation nor any examples. I guess there is a specification somewhere in the archives at Microsoft, but it doesn't seem to be available online.

The clearest definition of the non-xml format I've seen is this image (taken from [Structure of Non-XML Format Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx#Structure)):

[image: Structure of Non-XML Format Files]

For me that is proof enough that comments are not a part of the format and **the answer to your question is NO**.

As pointed out in the comment by Katherine Elizabeth Lightsey using the newer XML-based format files might be a better, more flexible option, with the added bonus that the XML-format is pretty much self-describing.

Answer (score 1):

Not allowing comments in the format file is only the 47th most miserable thing about `bcp`.

I needed this too, and as my workflow was already using a wrapper script, a small bit of PowerShell easily filters the documented format file into a temporary one that `bcp` would accept:

```
...
Get-Content $commentedformatfile |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.StartsWith("#") } |
    Set-Content "_temp.fmt"
...
bcp ... -f _temp.fmt ...
```

This simple mechanism only supports comments via a `#` character at the start of a line, but it was entirely suitable for me.

Note that `bcp` barfs on *even a blank line* so you still have to pay attention.